# get ip address of a user who is accessing my bot developed using bot framework(using c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I want to get IP Address of a user who is accessing my chat bot. I tried several options but I am getting the IP Address of the server in which my bot is hosted. Is there any way to get the user's IP?

Comment: How does the user access your chatbot? Are you using the WebChat or another channel. If you are using the WebChat, are you using the iframe or a selfhosted implementation.

Comment: Check HttpContext Request ServerVariables for IP Address

Comment: @Mick I am using bot web chat and MSteams channel. I did not use iframe and I am using the web chat channel that is in-built in azure for testing purposes

Comment: @Sonal Borkar I tried the server variables and it is returning ::1 as output. I used ngrok to make my bot endpoint public and tested. It still shows the same 1.

Comment: @Arun7even Which key of ServerVariables have you accessed?

Comment: @Sonal Borkar ["REMOTE_ADDR"]variable. Is that correct?..Please share the code if you have any.

Comment: Why do you need the users ip address? You can't retrieve it from Microsoft Teams at all and from Webchat not by default.

Comment: @Mick We need IP Address as few operations in our bot relys on it.

Comment: @Arun7even ::1 is localhost in IPv6. so try with "http://127.0.0.1/" or "http://machine-name" for IPv4 format IP Address

Comment: @Arun7even could you be more clear about your usecase? I don't think retrieving the user ip address would be the way to go.

Comment: @Mick We are checking the user's IP Address range by getting the address from the bot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't retrieve a users IP address using the default methods `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, since the (Azure) Bot Connector Service is in between. You don't have a direct connection with the end-user and the Bot Connector Service doesn't pass the users public ip address.

- Microsoft Teams doesn't allow this at all, a possible workaround would be to open a custom website in a popup / tab / browser where you log the ip address for the current user.
- WebChat (with DirectLine service) does not support this by default, but you can [leverage the backchannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to send the ip address as a custom event.

---

I can't see why you need the users public ip address, except for authentication. If you would need it for authentication, my choice would be to implement authentication using Azure Active Directory or another identity provider. [Add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: I've got this need as well. The purpose is to identify the user location without having to ask for it, by using IP GeoLocation services. There is no way to call the Azure Bot Service passing the conversation id to get back the original client IP? This is for cases where customizing the channel to pass this data is not an option.

Comment: @gonzaedu61 unfortunately not. What would be the case where you can not customize the channel?

Comment: I also want to get the users IP address. For a different reason. We want to block the IP addresses of malicious users. We do not want to use authentication as our users have no accounts. Using the directline backchannel would not work for us because a malicious user could edit the front end code to send a fake IP. I thougt of using the C# BotController or the TokenController to find the users IP and connect it to the user id. Could this be done?

Answer (score -4):

Try below to get IP Address of Client Machine

```
   string VisitorsIPAddress = string.Empty;
   if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
     {
        VisitorsIPAddress = 
      HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
     }
   else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
     {
        VisitorsIPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
     }
   else         
     {
         VisitorsIPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     }
```

Comment: Thanks!!..I'll try this one